# Powershell Script to archive as zip files based on file name

Tags: powershell

I am new to powershell, could you please help me in powershell script to archive as zip files based on file name and destination file name should use file created date. 
   Please find the sample scenario for the same.

**Source Folder : (C:\documents\dailyfiles)**

```
A0001.dat created date : 2014-10-01
B0001.dat created date : 2014-10-01
C0001.dat created date : 2014-10-01
D0001.dat created date : 2014-10-01
A0002.dat created date : 2014-10-02
B0002.dat created date : 2014-10-02
C0002.dat created date : 2014-10-02
D0002.dat created date : 2014-10-02
A0003.dat created date : 2014-10-03
B0003.dat created date : 2014-10-03
C0003.dat created date : 2014-10-03
D0003.dat created date : 2014-10-03
.
.
.
A0010.dat created date : 2014-10-10
B0010.dat created date : 2014-10-10
C0010.dat created date : 2014-10-10
D0010.dat created date : 2014-10-10
```

**Destination Folder (C:\documents\Archive)**

```
Arch_0001_20141001.zip
Arch_0002_20141002.zip
Arch_0003_20141003.zip
.
.
.
Arch_0010_20141010.zip
```

Each zip file will have A,B,C and D.dat file. Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

Thanks,
Prasad.

Comment: -1 for missing solution attempt. What's the *exact* question? How to group files by name? By date? To create an archive? What external tools, if any, can be used?

Comment: Also, which PowerShell version? From PowerShell 3.0 / .NET 4.5, `System.IO.Compression.FileSystem can` be used to create ZIP archives natively.

Answer (score 1):

Please give this a try. (You will need PowerShell 3.0.)

```
$SFOLDER= "C:\temp"
$DSTFOLDER="C:\temp2"

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.IO.Compression.FileSystem')
[System.Type]$typeAcceleratorsType=[System.Management.Automation.PSObject].Assembly.GetType('System.Management.Automation.TypeAccelerators',$true,$true)

$TMP=@()
Get-ChildItem $SFOLDER |%{
$TMP += New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property @{'Name' = $_.name
                                                       'Date' = (get-date($_.CreationTime) -Format "yyyy-MM-dd")}
}

$TMP|Group-Object DATE|%{
   New-Item -path $DSTFOLDER -name $_.Group[0].Date  -itemtype directory ;
   foreach($i in $_.Group){
           Copy-item  ($SFOLDER+"\"+$i.Name)  ($DSTFOLDER+"\"+$_.Group[0].Date)
       }
   [System.IO.Compression.Zipfile]::CreateFromDirectory( ($DSTFOLDER+"\"+$_.Group[0].Date),($DSTFOLDER+"\"+$_.Group[0].Date+".zip"))
   Remove-Item -Recurse ($DSTFOLDER+"\"+$_.Group[0].Date)
}
```

Comment: Hi, We are using powershell version 2.0. Files has to be grouped based on the created date.